# ERROR 404 when redirecting a View after migrate from springframework 2.5.6 to 3.2.8

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, migration

I've migrated my application from springframework 2.5.6 to 3.2.8, keeping all the same controllers and config files.

I just changed the XML Schema files from

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">
```

and replacing jar files:

```
<include name="**/spring-2.5.6.jar"/>
<include name="**/spring-webmvc-2.5.6.jar"/>
```

with

```
<include name="**/spring/spring-core-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar"/>
<include name="**/spring/spring-web-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar"/>
<include name="**/spring/spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar"/>
<include name="**/spring/spring-aop-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar"/>
<include name="**/spring/spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar"/>
<include name="**/spring/spring-context-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar"/>
<include name="**/spring/spring-context-support-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar"/>    
<include name="**/spring/spring-expression-3.2.8.RELEASE"/>
<include name="**/spring/spring-jdbc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar"/>               
<include name="**/spring/spring-orm-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar"/>
<include name="**/spring/spring-jdbc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar"/>
<include name="**/spring/spring-tx-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar"/>
<include name="**/spring/spring-instrument-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar"/>
```

But redirecting one to another Controller does not work anymore and I get an ERROR 404

Thanks

Comment: This include `**/spring/spring-instrument-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar.jar` does not look rigt (`.jar` is doubled)

Comment: Need more details: code for redirect, error logs, etc...